# UICollectionView cells not showing when I set the height too low

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm trying to add a UICollectionView to my view to use as a scrolling date picker on a single line. I'd like this to be relatively compact, but I'm having trouble when setting the collection view's height in IB.

Basically if I drop the height of the frame below 114, my prototype cells disappear, and no cells are displayed when I run the app. As long as it's above that value, everything works fine.

I've also got a black bar of empty background space above the cells despite setting their height to the same as the frame's height in sizeForItemAtIndexPath.

My delegate and datasource are set up correctly, and my cell has an identifier set and is being dequeued just fine, as long as the view's height is large enough. Do I need to subclass UICollectionViewLayout to get a really short view to work?

Comment: The height of the collection view should not be a problem. I have implemented collection views shorter than that. Surely, you are missing something. Consider providing more details about how you are setting it up.

Comment: OK weird, it was a very simple setup so I didn't think it was worth mentioning, but just to be sure I went to create an even simpler one just now to test before replying - empty ViewController with a CollectionView - and that one works. Something must have gotten weird in IB with this one view. Thanks!

Comment: Found the cause of the problem. Embedding the ViewController in a NavigationController causes the CollectionView to do something weird to its cells: https://www.dropbox.com/s/syrrj86t4n7qcua/Screenshot%202015-10-02%2010.33.12.png?dl=0 versus https://www.dropbox.com/s/fv3z8hbck4w24tm/Screenshot%202015-10-02%2010.33.43.png?dl=0

Comment: Hmm... try unchecking automatically adjusts scroll view insets on your View Controller.

Comment: Ahh, that seems to have done it! Want to submit that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uncheck `Adjusts Scroll View Insets` on your view controller or set `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` property on the view controller to false programmatically.